# How to handle insert with Hibernate and ColdFusion on the primary key

Tags: hibernate, coldfusion, oracle11g, coldfusion-10

I have been trying to solve this one for a while. What is the correct approach for inserting into a table using Hibernate and ColdFusion 10 and Oracle 11g? Nothing seems to work. I have tried almost everything [in the documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSB7BEC0B4-8096-498d-8F9B-77C88878AC6C.html#WSA1F7CC44-F5A0-419c-B988-EC230EFF192E).

Here is the code that I have:

```
property name="ID" column="ID" 
       type="numeric" 
       ormtype="double" 
       fieldtype="id" 
       generator="native";
```

Comment: I do not have an answer, but it would probably help to expand on "Nothing seems to work". ie What are the actual results of the code above? If you are getting an error message, please [include it in your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26745467/edit).

Comment: Why are you using `double` for a PK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much looking around and testing this is the solution that I found which works in Oracle 11g and ColdFusion 10 on Solaris. I simply need to change the ormtype="double" to ormtype="int" I handled the sequence by doing this. generator="sequence" sequence="sequencename"
Here is the code.

```
property name="ID" column="ID" type="numeric" ormtype="int" fieldtype="id" generator="sequence" sequence="sequencename";
```

Comment: Isn't that what Scott suggested in his answer and comments?

Comment: Nice...you answer your own question with exactly what I suggested...and then marked your own answer as 'accepted' Good luck getting help in the future.

Comment: Hi Scott, I tried your suggestion before you posted on the Ortus Solution tool Databoss and it errored. The Databoss tool does not accept the params structure. Sorry, but your suggestion did not work for me in a non databoss orm situation I am sure it would; but in my situation it did not sorry.

Comment: No where in you question do you mention you were using Databoss. That is information that is relevant to the problem at hand.

Answer (score 3):

The answer was in the link you provided. For Oracle, you need to provide information about which sequence to use for auto-increment IDs.

```
<cfproperty name="id" fieldtype="id" 
     generator="sequence" 
     params="{sequence='id_sequence'}">
```